# USB 3 drive not detected on USB 3 port

Tags: usb, usb-drive

Usb3 drives (external hard disk or flashdrive) are not not seen on usb3 ports.

They work perfectly on USB2 ports. A USB2 flashdrive works perfectly on uSB2 or USB3 port.

The light on the USB3 disk drive flashes for about 1 second and nothing happens on the system, nothing appears in `dmesg` or in `lsusb`

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 LTS (kernel 4.4.0-92-lowlatency) on a Gigabit 78UMT-USB3 mother board.

What's the problem here and how can I solve it?